# Get JSON object from server-side Python into client-side Django template

Tags: javascript, django, json

Server-side, in Python, I'm returning a JSON object that looks like this:

```
 contactAddr = {'name' : name, …}
 contactAddrJSON = json.dumps(contactAddr)
```

Client side, I'm using Django's template engine to dump that string into a javascript variable, and turning that into an object like this:

```
 var _myAddressObj = '{{ contactAddrJSON|safe}}';
 var adrObj = $.parseJSON(_myAddressObj);
```

This worked fine, until I got something where *name* had a single-quote in it.  I've spent the past couple of hours trying to figure out all these levels of string escapes to get the damn object into Javascript, but to no avail.  I just need it to be robust to single and double quotes.  Can someone enlighten me?  My brain is smoking.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the parsing process. Most JSON data is actually syntactically valid JavaScript, so you can put it directly into the source:

```
var adrObj = {{ contactAddrJSON|safe}};
```

Comment: This still messes things up, since the single-quote winds up closing off the string, and then the rest of the string contents is interpreted as code.

Comment: Then there is something else wrong. Strings in JSON are always in double quotes, so it is not possible for a single quote to prematurely close a string. Maybe the `safe` option somehow messes up the output?